# PHP - htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I am attempting to use "htmlspecialchars" function to sanitize URLs. Below is the code:

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new;
```

The anticipated output should be:

```
&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

However what I get is:

```
<a href='test'>Test</a>
```

It is not actually stripping the special characters at all. Am I doing something incorrectly? The above example is a copy and paste directly from php.net.

I am using PHP Version 5.4.8.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the source code? I have the same version and it works fine for me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in any version since 4.3.11: http://3v4l.org/Y6JdB

Comment: How do you test the output? You aren't viewing it on an HTML page in a browser, right? If so, what you get makes perfect sense.

Comment: No, I think it has something to do with my specific installation of PHP. I uploaded my files to my website on a actual host server and I am not having issues whatsoever. On my own computer, I am having an issue though.

I'm looking at the actual source, not the browser window. (Right click->View Page Source).

Comment: I am wondering why I got down voted.... My question was clear, concise and included version numbers. I explained my output and commented how I was reviewing my source code. If I did something wrong... let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run that, the output I get is:

```
&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

Either:

- Your PHP interpretor is broken
- You are looking at the *rendered* HTML and not the HTML source

Comment: It appears my interpretor must be broken. Thanks for the information. I am using Chrome and right clicking on the page to view the source and I am not getting the correct output, however when I upload my source to my web server on an actual host, I get the proper output.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Ryan For ultimate confirmation, use `curl` on the command line or a similar tools which gives you the guaranteed raw output of whatever the server sends. Or just run PHP on the command line. I would not trust modern browsers to show me the raw raw source at any stage.

Comment: @Ryan — An actual host? Where you were running the PHP before? Did you have a webserver? If not then the problem wasn't that your PHP interpretor was broken, but that you weren't using one at all.